# Loss of graph connectivity when importing graph from geodataframes

Tags: python, geopandas, osmnx

I am currently trying to find the shortest paths along street networks for different node pairs.

I extracted an XML file representing a street network using Overpass Turbo and made a graph from that file using OSMNX graph_from_file function. I extracted nodes and edges information using OSMNX graph_to_gdfs function, wherein I got 2 geodataframes. Consequently, I edited the information under the 'highway' column of the edge geodataframe to suit my needs. I did not make any other change. Then I made a new graph using the node and edge geodataframe using OSMNX gdfs_to_graph function, which should be similar to the graph extracted from the XML file, barring some changes in the edge data.

Now as I try to find the shortest path from one node to the other in the graph, it shows connectivity error. I tried to find the shortest path between the same node pair using the graph imported directly from the XML file and that works perfectly. In another scenario, I did not make any modifications to the geodataframes and went through the entire process which does not work as well. This means that there is some issue regarding the connectivity when graphs are imported from geodataframes which I cannot understand. Can someone please address this issue?

```py
G_multiDi = ox.graph_from_file('overpass_ped_PTstop_export.xml', bidirectional=False, simplify=True, retain_all=True, name='unnamed') 
G_undi = G_multiDi.to_undirected()
fig, ax = ox.plot_graph(G_undi)
nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_undi, nodes=True, edges=False)
edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G_undi, nodes=False, edges=True)

In [43]: nx.shortest_path(G_undi,35524093,35365678,weight = 'length')
Out[43]: [35524093, 53132201, 35524331, 1994687832, 35365678]

#GEODATAFRAME TO GRAPH
gdf_nodes = nodes
gdf_edges = edges
graph2 = ox.gdfs_to_graph(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges)

nx.shortest_path(graph2,35524093,35365678,weight = 'length')
In [47]: nx.shortest_path(graph2,35524093,35365678,weight = 'length')
NetworkXNoPath: No path to 35365678.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I fixed the problem myself by converting the directed graph 'graph2' resulting from graph2 = ox.gdfs_to_graph(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges) 
to an undirected graph using 
graph2 = graph2.to_undirected().

```py
graph2 = ox.gdfs_to_graph(gdf_nodes, gdf_edges) 
graph2 = graph2.to_undirected()

In [72]: nx.shortest_path(graph2,35524093,35365678,weight = 'length')
Out[72]: [35524093, 53132201, 35524331, 1994687832, 35365678]
```